# i am trying to send an email from ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am in dead end! i am trying to make an app to receive emails on hotmail! i created a method and i am getting an error and no email receiving..

in my method:

```
class Recivemail < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :from, :subject

 def sendmail(content,from,subject)
    subject = 'subject'
    recipients = "linkinpark_8884@hotmail.com"
    from = 'from'
    sent_on = Time.now
  end 
end
```

in config>enviroments>development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings ={
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address => 'smtp.hotmail.com',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :domain => 'localhost:3000',
    :user_name => 'linkinpark_8884@hotmail.com',
    :password => 'mypass'

  }
```

in views>recivemails>show

```
<%=@recivemail.sendmail(@recivemail.from,@recivemail.subject,@recivemail.content)%>
```

everything seems to working correct except that i am not getting any email any ideas??
also in cmd (i am in windows) on path C:/Sites/recivemail path i have run gem install activemailer

Comment: I seem to remember people having a bunch of problems with hotmail for this kind of thing... you might try gmail instead. (besides, hotmail for me just implies spam ;])

Comment: Please include the error messages and stack trace.

Comment: how? (i am new at this) @opensourcechris

Comment: How are you running the app? In development by running 'rails s' from the app root?

Comment: Post the error you mentioned in the first line of your question.

Comment: @opensourcechris in cmd yes i use 'rails s' to run the app. i am not getting any errors to mention it... the only thing is that i am not getting emails and i dont know why..

Comment: check in the file logs/development.txt, see if there are any clues there.

Comment: One think I can tell you for sure is that Windows is not the optimal OS to be developing rails on. That alone makes this a little more difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: nothing unusual in development.txt.....@opensourcechris

i thing is something with the deliver....

Comment: Try a different delivery service such as @varatis suggested. gmail should work fine.

Comment: i have try it... i changed it to gmail and nothing changed same thing... not receiving email.. @opensourcechris

Comment: @varatis i have change it to gmail and nothing has changed.. still not receiving email.. any idea??

Comment: I don't understand why there are no error messages or texts. It just fails silently?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in your sendmail method that actually sends the mail. All you have done is set 4 instance variables. i don't think you actually tried to send the mail. I also don't see where you set the content parameter to a variable in the method.

I also think your mailer object should descend from ActionMailer::Base

```
class ReceiveMail < ActionMailer::Base
  default :return_path => 'system@example.com'

  def sendmail(content,from,subject)
     mail(:to => "linkinpark_8884@hotmail.com",
         :bcc => ["bcc@example.com", "Order Watcher <watcher@example.com>"],
             :subject => subject,
             :content => content) # use whatever mail headers are appropriate
  end

end
```

Then in your controller, not your model, call `.deliver` on the ActionMailer::Base object model you create in your controller action NOT in the active record model.

Controller might look like this

```
class MailController < ApplicationController
def mails
  ReceiveMail.sendmails(params[])
   @message = ReceiveMail(params[content], params[subject], params[from]) #pass params if form POST
   @message.deliver
end

end
```

You might also have to define this:

```
ActionMailer::Base.template_root = "mailer/templates"
  # mailer will look for rhtml templates in that path
  # example: "mailer/templates/my_mailer/signup_mail.rhtml"
```

in config/environments/development.rb/production.rb

Comment: where i have to create ActionMailer::Base??? i must delete class Recivemail < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :from, :subject

 def sendmail(content,from,subject)
    subject = 'subject'
    recipients = "linkinpark_8884@hotmail.com"
    from = 'from'
    sent_on = Time.now
  end 
end

and replace it with your code??

Comment: No, don't place yours with my code. Let me edit my answer to reflect your data, in the mean time, read this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html, all of it, from top to bottom.

Comment: i have read the link!! it was very helpfull BUT i don't have class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base! i have class Recivemail < ActiveRecord::Base! what i must do??

Comment: In your model, Change the text 'ActiveRecord' to 'ActionMailer'. Then in your CONTROLLER method is where you create an instance of Receivemail. Then you call .deliver on that object.

Comment: ok, check out the answer now, i changed it to match your scenario

Comment: lol.... i have change the activeREcord to ActionMailer and now.....Routing Error
undefined method `attr_accessible' for Recivemail:Class

Comment: comment out the attr_accessible. I do not think you need formal attributes for a mailer. Check out my updated answer

Comment: LoadError in RecivemailsController#index 
Expected C:/Sites/sendmail/app/models/recivemail.rb to define RecivemailRails.root: C:/Sites/sendmail
app/controllers/recivemails_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: If the index action is where you wnat this to happen make sure your view is named index, in the question you have the view in "views>recivemails>show" make it in "views>recivemails>index", and see if that changes the error. Disclaimer, windows sucks.

Comment: the problem is when i changing the activeREcord to ActionMailer.. i have try and your suggest to rename them but still having problem

Comment: checkout my latest edit at the bottom of the question, you might have to define the directory where your templates are stored. I guess rails does not routes the same for mailers as it does normal controller actions and templates.

Comment: nop... nothing!! omg i am so tier and mad with the email thing.... thx for helping

Comment: in cmd i have wrote the command: rails generate scaffold recivemail from:string subject:string content:string 

this creates the  ActiveRecord !!!
i have to put another command to create the ActionMailer???

Comment: forget the scaffold. create all components for your mailer from scratch. cmd 'scaffold destroy recivemail', Create the mailer model, controller method and template, and add the mailer root to your development.rb. All you need is in my answer, start over without scaffolds.

Comment: i was having a mistake and i fix it!! now is working but when goes to controller on this part  ReceiveMail.sendmails(params[])
  ' @'message = ReceiveMail(params[content], params[subject], params[from]) #pass params if form POST
  ' @'message.deliver
   

SAYS NameError in RecivemailsController#create 
uninitialized constant RecivemailsController::ReceiveMail

Comment: try to remove the params[] from the sendmails arguments, you might need to assign the params to local variables and pass them to sendmails like normal parameters.i.e. sendmails(arg1, arg2, arg3), If my answer was right please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.coupa.org/2006/12/12/receiving-emails-with-actionmailer-on-windows/